# Wordpress spam Admin account

Tags: wordpress, admin, block, registration, spam

I noticed that there is someone who registers himself as admin, his role is "Administrator", and can change my website settings. I keep delete him, and he then adds himself again.

I just get email confirmation "New User Registeration", and then I noticed that my website "url" changed from the settings to "getmyfreetrafic.com", then I restore it from "MySQL".

I have this settings:

* Registeration is closed, I do not have new registeration allowed

* I have Wordfence installed.

* I have the latest Wordpress version.

How can he register himself as an admin again and again?

And how to block this spam?

Thanks

Comment: you are probably already hacked. once a backdoor is installed, wordfence and settings do not help. it's very easy to add users when code can be executed on the server, . i would recommend to delete all files and replace them with fresh downloads.

Comment: Unfortunately I must aggree with @Beatroot, it seems like you are already hacked. There are probably infected files on the server already... I would suggest having a look at your index.php files for malicious code or your wp-config.php and also looking at your root directory for suspicious files. Unfortunately there is no 1 solution to this, it can vary.

Comment: by the way, a few days later there was this news: https://www.pluginvulnerabilities.com/tag/getmyfreetraffic-com/   the culprit is the plugin "Easy WP SMTP". it had a vulnerability that allowed creating admin accounts. if you are lucky, you can simply fix the problem in the database. in this case, im not certain if they are opening new backdoors, which would be easy once a installation is compromised. you'll have to investigate.  generally, if hacked, delete all files and redownload them. it's like 1h of work usually and it gives peace of mind.

Comment: Thanks Beatroot, you are totally right. It was from "Easy WP SMTP" which I am already using. I deleted it and checked all the files, replace any modified one with the original one. Now it is 80% better and I am keeping checking and deleting strange files.